# Change Back Button Behaviour - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, back

I have an application . The flow is -
**Splash Screen ---> Home Screen ---> Item List Screen ---> Item Details Screen**

In my application i have **home** button functionality on **Item List Screen** and **Item Details Screen**.

When i press **Home Button** on **Item Details screen** it goes back to **Home Screen** . This is expected behaviour. 
But when i press **back button** on **Home screen** , it takes me back to the **Item Details Screen**.(*this is what i dont want*)

I tried killing the **Item Details Screen** using **finish()**, But then the last activity in the activity stack is Item List Screen. 
The Back button on Home screen now takes me to the Item List Screen . 
Is there any way to clear the activity stack when user is on Home Screen . Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should launch your *Home Screen* Activity with additional intent flags:

```
// create intent
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the activity stack up to the Home Screen activity. This activity will simply be presented, not recreated. Also, this guarantees that there will be only one Home Screen activity which is likely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Intent [flag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags%28int%29) [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) to clear the stack:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

You should call this code when the 'Home button' is pressed.